# Matrix Factorization find from which users score is generated

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am building a user based recommendation engine with Python and [LightFM](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm) and I am trying to figure out how the score of a user to product is generated from the other users.

Specifically, I am trying to answer the following questions:

1) Which users influence the predicted score of an another user over a product?

2) How can I find these users?

Answer (score 0):

I studied a document talking about it, actually you will find a lot of articles on google if you search for "representative users" or even "seed users" terms